# How do I get more specific duration using Google Charts Timeline?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

So, I'm using the following code to create a timeline from Google charts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById("example1");

    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "RowName" });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "Label" });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "date", id: "Start" });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: "date", id: "End" });

    dataTable.addRows([
      ["Row1", "Step 1", new Date(2013, 11, 4, 2, 45, 0), new Date(2013, 11, 4, 4, 5, 15)],
      ["Row1", "Step 2", new Date(2013, 11, 4, 4, 5, 15), new Date(2013, 11, 7, 8, 34, 55)],
      ["Row1", "Step 3", new Date(2013, 11, 7, 8, 34, 55), new Date(2013, 11, 12, 11, 28, 49)],
      ["Row1", "Step 4", new Date(2013, 11, 12, 11, 28, 49), new Date(2013, 11, 14, 9, 27, 17)]
    ]);

    var options = {
        timeline: {
            groupByRowLabel: true,
            showRowLabels: true
        }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
</script>
<div id="example1" style="width: 900px; height: 180px;"></div>
```

I would like to get more detailed with the mouse over popup Duration.  If you look at Step 1, it just says Duration: 1 day.  But, if you look at the code, it was only an hour 20 minutes and 15 seconds.  Is there any way to get this to show?

Link of code running: http://jsfiddle.net/ifandelse/FdFM3/

Comment: The Timeline visualization does not yet support formatting the duration or using custom tooltips, either of which would be required to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct what user *asgallant* said. But still you can get some information.

Add one element after you chart `div`:

```
<div id="example1" style="width: 900px; height: 180px;"></div>
<div id='duration'></div>
```

Add event listener before call to draw chart:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (obj) {

    var startDate = dataTable.getValue(obj.row, 2);
    var endDate   = dataTable.getValue(obj.row, 3);

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());
    var diffDays = (timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

    var durationEl = document.getElementById('duration');
    durationEl.innerHTML = 'Duration: ' + diffDays.toFixed(4);
});

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

You will get now for the 1st step 0.0557. This solution is little ugly but at least you get an idea. You can even calculate hours if you want and do some styling.

See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ENajOxUC/1/edit).

Comment: What you posted definitely works, but how does obj get reference to the moused over row?  I ask this because right now I'm trying to get clientX and I can't figure out how to send event to the function.

Comment: I don't know how it works internally. If you check docs [Timeline/Events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Events) there is written that object provided will have row and column information. Row is the only information provided, column is anyway known. If you mean with `clientX` position of mouse pointer, I don't know how you will get this information. You can try to figure it somehow from SVG markup. See console, DOM Elements...

Comment: Thanks @AntoJurković for your answer ! that was helpful ! 
I have another problem, onmouseover here is fired only when the cursor hovers an event inside a row, but not when the cusor hovers a row, i want it to fire when the cursor is on a row even if the row is empty with no events on it, is that possible ? thanks again

Comment: @YAT: I didn't manage to get that. I tried even to add `mouseover` event handler with `addEventListener` to complete drawing element but it seems that google api masks it.